# Finding database data that best fits user variable responses

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql

I am trying to return the best matching items from my database given some user selection. My database columns link to an enum table.  The enum options are either true, false, or maybe.  When a user answers true for a question that corresponding column in the database must also be true. When a user answers false for a question that column in the database can be ignored.  When a user answers maybe for a question I want to order my results by best matches.

Example:
Venue_Table

```
id  name  parking  decorations  hotel
1   park     1          2         1
2   beach    1          2         2
3   theater  2          2         2
4   yard     2          1         1
```

Response_Enum_Table

```
id     value
1      TRUE
2      FALSE
3      MAYBE
```

My backend will receive an object with user responses, for example `{parking: MAYBE, decorations: FALSE, hotel: TRUE}`.  My query needs to return venues that have hotel set to true.  The query can ignore the decorations column since the user selected false.  Finally, the query should order responses by venues with parking set to true.

As requested I will post what I have currently. This will return a list of venues ordered by best match if the user has entered maybe for each response.  I still need to figure out how to enforce matching when users answer true and disregard columns where users answer false.

```
SELECT venue_name
FROM venue_table
ORDER BY cast(boolcol1 IS TRUE AS integer) +
         cast(boolcol2 IS TRUE AS integer) +
         cast(boolcol3 IS TRUE AS integer) DESC;
```

Comment: You forgot to post your query and the problem you have with it.

Comment: I updated the question now.  My current query doesn't account for when the user answers true or false. Also it isn't checking the enum table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the "enum" value for each column. (That seems to be the main thing you're missing.)

In the `WHERE` clause you can then filter for the things that have to equal `'TRUE'`.

Use an `ORDER BY` for the things that are `'MAYBE'`. Compare them to `'TRUE'` and cast that comparison to an `integer`. Sum the results of that casted comparisons and sort by that sum descending.

```
SELECT v.venue_name
       FROM venue_table v
            INNER JOIN response_enum_table rp
                       ON rp.id = v.parking
            INNER JOIN response_enum_table rd
                       ON rd.id = v.decorations
            INNER JOIN response_enum_table rh
                       ON rh.id = v.hotel
         -- INNER JOIN response_enum_table rx
         --            ON rx.id = v.x
         -- INNER JOIN response_enum_table ry
         --            ON ry.id = v.y
         -- ...
       WHERE rh.value = 'TRUE'
          -- AND rx.value = 'TRUE'
          -- ...
       ORDER BY (rp.value = 'TRUE')::integer
             -- + (ry.value = 'TRUE')::integer
             -- ...
                DESC;
```

Side note: Postgres offers enums as data types itself. You could change the venue table's schema to use these, then the joins wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I think I understand the joining.  I am a little confused on the WHERE clause.  What is rh and rx in this case?

Comment: @tdammon: They're table aliases. Notice them after the table name in the `FROM`s/`JOIN`s. They get declared there and then can be used instead of the table name in the rest of the query. Since we join the same table several times they're even mandatory here to distinguish which "instance" of the table we mean in the rest of the query.

Comment: @ sticky bit Got it thank you.  I still don't see how this WHERE clause will filter by my user selection.  This seems to be filtering by venues that have TRUE for a particular column but how is the user selection factored in?

Comment: @tdammon: Your application has to build such a query of course. With the columns and values it has been given by the user.

Comment: So than would I need to add a WHEN statement into the query? Or would this be something my backend would need to construct?

Comment: @tdammon: There's no `WHEN` statement in (Postgres) SQL. Maybe you mean a `CASE` expression. Or a `CASE` statements but the latter isn't in (Postgres) SQL either but in PL/pgSQL. But PL/pgSQL is a different language. But none of them are needed here. And yes, I think it would be easiest thing for you, if your application does construct the query. You're probably more familiar with the language your application is written in. But you could, in theory, also create a PL/pgSQL function that does the job.

Comment: Ok I think I have things working.  I am getting the data returned in the correct order, although there are some extra columns coming in that aren't in my database. (If you're interested I posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64200105/postgresql-query-returning-values-that-are-not-in-my-database).