# PostgreSQL query returning values that are not in my database

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, backend

I am working on constructing a query to my database to return some data.  Here is the link to a previous post describing my intentions [Finding database data that best fits user variable responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64198465/finding-database-data-that-best-fits-user-variable-responses/64198715?noredirect=1#comment113524255_64198715).  I want to return all of the columns for each data object, however the id that is returned is not correct and an additional `VALUE` field is being returned.

My database is set up like this
venues

```
id  name  parking  decorations  hotel
1   park     1          2         1
2   beach    1          2         2
3   theater  2          2         2
4   yard     2          1         1
```

and an enum table

```
id     value
1      TRUE
2      FALSE
3      MAYBE
```

I am building a query on my backend as follows:

```
  let searchConstraintsTrue = 'WHERE';
  let firstItemTrue = 0;
  for (const prop in req.body) {
    if (req.body[prop] === 'TRUE') {
      if (firstItemTrue === 0) {
        searchConstraintsTrue += ` ${prop} = 1`;
        firstItemTrue++;
      } else {
        searchConstraintsTrue += ` AND ${prop} = 1`;
      }
    }
  }

  let searchConstraintsMaybe = 'ORDER BY';
  let firstItemMaybe = 0;
  for (const prop in req.body) {
    if (req.body[prop] === 'MAYBE') {
      if (firstItemMaybe === 0) {
        searchConstraintsMaybe += ` (${prop} = 1)::integer`;
        firstItemMaybe++;
      } else {
        searchConstraintsMaybe += ` + (${prop} = 1)::integer`;
      }
    }
  }

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
  let sqlText = `SELECT * FROM venues 
  INNER JOIN response_enum rp ON rp.id = venues.parking 
  INNER JOIN response_enum rd ON rd.id = venues.decorations 
  INNER JOIN response_enum rh ON rh.id = venues.hotel 
  ${searchConstraintsTrue} ${searchConstraintsMaybe} DESC`;
```

I realize that my `searchConstraintsTrue` and `searchConstraintsMaybe` are not properly using the enum table but right now I am just trying to get things working.

An example response looks like this:

```
[  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'beach',
    parking: 1,
    decorations: 2,
    hotel: 1,
    value: 'TRUE'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'yard',
    parking: 1,
    decorations: 2,
    hotel: 2,
    value: 'FALSE'
  }]
```

So I am returning the desired data however the `id`'s are incorrect and there is a value column which doesn't exist in my database.

Comment: `value` and `id`are from the joined tables. Fully qualify your select fields. `SELECT v.id, v.name, ... FROM venues v ...`

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT *`  will select all fields from the joined tables. You need to specify a list of fully qualified field names like so:

```
SELECT v.id,v.name,v.parking,v.decorations,v.hotel FROM venues v 
  INNER JOIN response_enum rp ON rp.id = venues.parking 
  INNER JOIN response_enum rd ON rd.id = venues.decorations 
  INNER JOIN response_enum rh ON rh.id = venues.hotel 
  ${searchConstraintsTrue} ${searchConstraintsMaybe} DESC
```